# How to return an empty promise?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
  var updateLogin = function updateLogin() {
     var parameters = $location.search();
     if(parameters.votoken) {
         // return a promise
         return authenticationService.updateCurrentToken(parameters);
     }

    //just logout and redirect to match another route
    authenticationService.logout()['finally'](function logoutComplete() {
        $location.url('/unauthorized');
    });
  }

    var redirectToHome = function redirectToHome() {

    $injector.invoke(updateLogin).then(() => {
           //some action here
    });
  }  


  redirectToHome();
```

As you can see, 
if the `updateLogin` method matches a condition it will return a promise and it works fine, but if not, the method doesnt return a promise and redirect the user to a new location, then i get this error on console `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` and its obvious why. I would like to know what is the best approach to avoid that. If I return the `authenticationService.logout()` promise, how do I know if i will need to execute this method `$location.url('/unauthorized');` on the `.then(() =>` snippet?

Comment: `return Promise.reject(new Error('unauthorized'));` and in the calling code do `updateLogin().then(dostuff).catch(dootherstuff);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can return [`$q.reject()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject) in your `else`. Remember to also inject `$q`

Comment: then I have to execute the $location.url('/unauthorized') snippet on the .catch block?